# gnome-screensaver or xscreensaver is better regarding security?

Tags: screensaver

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I used to use gnome-screensaver.. but.. it happened too many times that when I closed the lid of my notebook, it suspended itself, OK, but after I wanted to turn it on again.. it just showed me my desktop instead of the login screen... (yes locking IS ENABLED)

**Q:** So is it wiser to use xscreensaver, rather then the default gnome-screensaver?

Comment: I am not sure what "furled" means in this context. Do you mean you closed the lid?

Comment: updated, yes, I wanted to mean that

Comment: I know this is _very_ late, but the laptop lid issue is fixed in new versions of xscreensaver if you use systemd; otherwise, there is a solution [in the manpage](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html#15) (explanation [here](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#cpu-halt))